# Creating new workout journal/tracker app need help establishing database/models to get started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby and Rails, made a few blogs etc. I am slowy learning the ruby language and rails framework. I am wanting to create a workout journal/tracker application and need help establishing the models and or to get me started on the right path. I basically want to be able to create a workout/different types of workouts (back, arms, legs, etc), be able to use the # of sets and reps used for that workout, how many days/which days a week, add, edit, delete the workouts, track weight loss/weight, track the workouts, reps, sets you did prior, set goals in the journal, track progress, eventually be able to share workouts etc. I know what I am looking to do just need help getting started and establishing what models to use and what associations to use. I know it seems like alot of info. Any help getting at all getting going would be awesome. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit tricky, since there are many styles of exercises -- N sets of M reps, pyramid, max lifts, etc. You may want [polymorphic associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations) in the final version.

But I think you'll have a more clear vision of where to take the project once you've built a few tables and classes; I think I'd start with a `Workout` class that `has_many` `WOSets` (don't use `Set`; having class names that conflict with built-in class names is way more irritating than you may think), and each `WOSet` `has_many` `Reps`. Then your `Reps` will keep track of count and weight. Store the *order* of the reps in the `WOSet`.

You'll also need a `Station` class for all the machines and exercises; probably your `WOSet` will `belongs_to` the `Station`, and the `Station` will `has_many` `WOSet`. (So you can retrieve all the sets ever performed on a specific station.)

I hope this quick sketch gets you to the point of playing with creating new workouts, new stations, and playing with the interface in `script/console`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Yea i know it seems a bit tricky or complicated but I think once I get going and creating some tables and model things will start to come together. First I think i need to decide what models I will be using with the workout journal. I am using rails 3 so hopefully i will have enough guidance out there for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Models = Tables

You should have a look at database design and normalization. Its paramount you get the basics right. Otherwise you might end up with database with common errors like performance issues and redundancy (which is is a bad thing).

One you understand what it is you need to store, mapping it to Rails is easy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization